# JQuery select all rows containing certain text within a td in the row

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have a table for which I am attempting to select all rows which have a td containing the text 'Test' and then hide the td with class 'ms-vb-icon' on all the matched rows

I intitally had the code below but this only hide the class on the last matched row

```
 $("td:contains('test'):last").parent().children(".ms-vb-icon").css("visibility","hidden");
```

So I tried this but its not working...

```
 $("tr:has(td:contains('test')").each(function(){
  (this).children(".ms-vb-icon").css("visibility","hidden");
  });
```

Simplified html look like this:

```
<table>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td class=ms-vb-icon></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td>test</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
<table>
```

Comment: Why not just remove `:last` from your original code?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Try:

```
$("tr td:contains('test')").each(function(){
  $(this).siblings('td.ms-vb-icon').css("visibility","hidden");
});
```

Demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/zHZLK/).

Comment: Thanks this worked great not sure what the difference between siblings and children is but this does the trick!

Comment: Children come belong under the td, so the td is the parent. Siblings belong next to the td, so it's another td in the same tr.

Comment: just a small point, if you are using jquery you might as wlel use .hide() rather than manually setting .css()

Answer (score 9):

Try with

```
$("tr:has(td:contains('test')").each(function(){
    $(this).parent().children(".ms-vb-icon").css("visibility","hidden");
});
```

The class `.ms-vb-icon` is a child of the `tr` while the `$(this)` function refer to the `td`

Comment: please note that I have also added a closing `"` before the each function. Anyway can you please post a sample markup?

Comment: Thanks but somehow the answer below works even though they both look the same to me...

Comment: As per tamarteleco, your code is missing a ')', that is why it doesn't work, please fix the code as I cant fix it for you.

Answer (score 8):

I guess you are missing ')' .It worked for me:

```
$("tr:has(td:contains('1'))").each(function () {
```