# Collect data from another site using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to build a calculator that will have to pull data from [another site](http://dev.zionsfx.com/FXLiveRateStream4.asp).

For example, if the user on my site selects the currency "BRL", I want to collect the rate "3.04" from [this site](http://dev.zionsfx.com/FXLiveRateStream4.asp). How can I do this?!

Please help. Thank you!!

Comment: Do they offer a JSON JSONP feed of the value? If not you will need to use a serverside technology to scrape it. refer to Same Origin Policy

Comment: I am not sure. I only have the url of that site

Comment: This link can help you to get the html from a url:
http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/cross-domain-requests-with-jquery/
And also this link can help you to get the content from the td with "BRL" content:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4341620/jquery-select-all-rows-containing-certain-text-within-a-td-in-the-row

Comment: @RicardoPontual, I think this is exactly what I am looking for....thank you SO much! Can you please post your comment as answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot do it because the security restriction BUT
on your site you create load.php file with the code:

```
<?php
$content = file_get_contents("http://dev.zionsfx.com/FXLiveRateStream4.asp");
echo $content;
```

and js code

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "http://yourSiteUrl/load.php",
        }).done(function( result ) {
         var tab = $(result).find('tr[title="Brazilian Real"]') .find('td:eq(1)');
  console.info(tab.text())
        });
```

the code is not really nice but it does what you wanted. So you can improve it in your free time

Comment: oh! this is brilliant! don't even have to worry about the SOP. I am going to try it out. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Did the solution work for you?

Answer (score 0):

This link can help you to get the html from a url: 
[james.padolsey.com/javascript/cross-domain-requests-with-jquery](http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/cross-domain-requests-with-jquery)

And also this link can help you to get the content from the td with "BRL" content: 
[JQuery select all rows containing certain text within a td in the row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4341620/jquery-select-all-rows-containing-certain-text-within-a-td-in-the-row)

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you for posting it as answer. I am working on it :)

Comment: Thank you for being the first person ACTUALLY trying to help me out here & posting a solution (unlike others who down voted and eventually "put on hold" my question o_O ) I gave u a +1 for that. But i had to pick @volkinc's solution as answer :<

Comment: Thank you @AlwaysANovice if still need any help just let us know.