# How to get html to return via javascript crossdomain

Tags: javascript, cross-domain

I'm using ebay and they allow javascript.  I want to return html from my domain.  However i only know jQuery and ebay doesn't allow jQuery.  Here is how i would call the file in jQuery.

```
var data: {
on:1
};
var url = "myfile.php";
jQuery.post(url,data,function(response)) {
$("#element").html(response);
});
```

php

```
    <?php 
 echo "<table><tr><th>test</th></tr></table>";
    die();
    ?>
```

How would i call the file in javascript?

Comment: That would be `XMLHttpRequest` if whatever context you are in allows you to make Http requests.

Comment: XMLHttpRequest - http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/xhr2/ - you'll need some CORS goodness too - http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/

Comment: can i have an example?

Comment: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/xhr2/ and http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/

Comment: I tried this `var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET', 'https://plantsandtreesonline.co.uk/wp-content/ebay_rss.php');
xhr.onload = function(e) {
  var data = JSON.parse(this.response);
 
}
xhr.send();` but how do i access the html?

Comment: @user892134 By using `xhr.open('GET', 'https://plantsandtreesonline.co.uk/wp-content/ebay_rss.php');` you're issuing a HTTP GET request to the server. In my opinion, you need a POST request. Check my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can probably imagine, sending custom Ajax requests with pure JavaScript is a little trickier. But it's not very hard. You don't need to change anything of your PHP file. But the equivalent JavaScript code for the Ajax request is:

### Ajax example using JavaScript:

```
var data = { on: 1 }; // the same data parameter on your code
var xmlhttp; // the XMLHttpRequest object
if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
  // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
}
else {
  // code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
// this is how you access the returned data
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
    // and bind it to your HTML
    document.getElementById("element").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
  }
}
xmlhttp.open("POST","myfile.php",true); // this prepares the Ajax call
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded"); // sets the correct request type for POST
xmlhttp.send(data); // actually sends the request
```

**Update:**
If you're getting an error about access control add this at the top of your PHP file:

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST');
```

**Reference:** http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/default.asp

Hope that answers your question.

Comment: I tried this but i get an error ` No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.`  What does that mean?  I'm testing on the same domain.  But when implemented it will be cross domain.

Comment: @user892134 This is because for Web security, cross domain Ajax request are not permitted. Wait, I'll post an updated answer on how to solve this problem.

Comment: Here is a similar question with a solution for crossdomain requests:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31419821/collect-data-from-another-site-using-javascript/31420463#31420463